# Using A Gem Installed To The System From Rake

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler, command-line-interface

I have a Rake task that uses the CLI of a gem called `fontcustom`. It hasn't received an update for a long while and its dependencies are incompatible with other Gems in my bundle, so I am unable to add it to the `Gemfile`.

I have the correct version installed on my system, but I can't see how to get the Rake task to use the system version. Without `fontcustom` in the `Gemfile`, running the rake task that references it gives me an error:

> fontcustom is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
>   (Gem::LoadError)

Can I explicitly tell the rake task to use the system version of `fontcustom`?

List gems:

```
$ gem list fontcustom
# fontcustom (1.3.3)
```

Task:

```
namespace :font do
  desc "Compile custom icon font"
  task :compile do
    Dir.chdir('resources/graphics/fonts/custom') do
       system 'fontcustom compile' # fontcustom is not part of the bundle.
       # `fontcustom compile` # fontcustom is not part of the bundle.
       # %x(fontcustom compile) # fontcustom compile: command not found
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So your shelling out with system or `\`\`` ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I've added results to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Bundler.with_clean_env`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb#L228-L238), which executes a block after resetting the various Bundler specific environment variables:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { system 'fontcustom compile' }
```

or the slightly more concise [`clean_system`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb#L240-L242) (which uses `with_clean_env`):

```
Bundler.clean_system 'fontcustom compile'
```